# Loading a dll file containing a winforms

Tags: c#, reflection

i have a solution cotaining two projects. A -> is a windowsforms project, B -> is a EXE project. I want to refrence A in B dynamically using the A.dll generated after build. but when i try to load A.dll in B and GetTypes(). I get this error :

```
    System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I tried loading System.Windows.Forms and all the referenced assemblies before gettypes but i ran into another error :

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

It seems that there is something that i can't figure out and im just running in closed loops.

My code :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\A.dll");
            
            var list = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().ToList();
            foreach (var asm in list) {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(asm);
                    }
            Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetTypes());
```

Comment: Just delete that foreach-loop, .net doesn't need that kind of help.  Won't otherwise eliminate the possible reason for that exception, beyond LoadFile, it is up to you to ensure both projects target the same .netcore version.  Or to enable roll-forward.